# Vue 3 global property is not visible in mounted or computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I've set a property in main.js:

```
app.config.globalProperties.$backendUrl  = "https://myhost:8989";
```

Then when getting it in the Component I get the following situation:

```
  methods: {
     save() {
        console.log(this.$backendUrl); //outputs CORRECT result
     }
  },

  mounted() {
     console.log(this.$backendUrl); //outputs undefined
  },

  computed: {
     treeData(){
        console.log(this.$backendUrl); //outputs undefined
     }
  }
```

What is wrong?

Comment: According to the docs this should work fine in `mounted`: https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-globalproperties You're not using arrow functions by any chance? e.g. `mounted: ()  => {`

Comment: Yep, no arrows. I've checked  this object in debug in mounted() - there is no field $backendUrl, however I see it within the method save(). save() is called on button click, nothin special.

Comment: If you log `this` is it the same object in `save` and in `mounted`?

Comment: they looks identical

Comment: I've also tested the follwing in mounted():    
    const app = getCurrentInstance();
    const burl = app.appContext.config.globalProperties.$backendUrl;
    console.log(burl);  // returns undefined

Comment: Well, it seems I've fixed. The problem was in fact that app.config.globalProperties.$backendUrl  = "https://myhost:8989";
was in the async block of configuring an app and it was ready far after mounted(), I'lve added await

Answer (score 1):

How is `app` defined in `main.js`?

That is, you should *not* do e.g.:

```
// app is component instance
const app = createApp(App).use(router).mount("#app");

app.config.globalProperties.$backendUrl = "https://myhost:8989";
```

Instead you should do:

```
// app is app instance
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router).mount("#app");

app.config.globalProperties.$backendUrl = "https://myhost:8989";
```

Comment: well, that was close, the problem was that setting this specific param was in the async block